# Unable to get grid store filters

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid store that looks like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.BufferedStore', {
    fields: fields,
    autoLoad: true,
    leadingBufferZone: 300,
    pageSize: 100,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'handler.php?action=getObjData&id_obj='+id_bj, 
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function () {
            //this is what I tried
            console.log(this.proxy.extraParams);
            console.log(this.proxy.params);
            console.log(this.proxy.url);
            console.log(this.filters.filterData());
        }
   }
```

});

As you can see, in a load listener I tried a number of solutions. But all of them result in `undefined`, `{}` or the initial url, event though wnen I filter data, I see in the console, that the server request becomes to look like:

```
handler.php?action=getObjData&filter=[{"operator":"gt","value":0,"property":"attr_88186_"}]...
```

So, there is a filter parameter, but I can not get it.

Comment: Have you tried to use functions of sencha docs?

Comment: Yes. I have found `filterData()` function, as you can see in my example, but still failed.

Comment: I mean, can you write the result of your console logs? the url console log returns the url or not?

Comment: First log returns `[]`, second - `undefined`, third - initial url without filter parameter, and the last one returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get the filters from a store:

```
load: function (store) {
    var filters = store.getFilters().getRange()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Though, `getRange` does not sound good for this task. They could have chosen a better method name. But still, thanks!

Comment: `filters` is a `mixedCollection`, and `getRange(start;end)` is the method of `mixedCollection` to get a certain range (start defaults to 0, end defaults to number of entries in the collection), so it makes sense, IMO. They could have renamed `filters` to `filtersCollection`, but they didn't, for reason of backwards compatibility.